# Set plsql parameters partially

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a query that when i enter partially the value of a parameter until"/" is shown it displays all the row sequences with that parameter in the first part before "/"

I enter as a parameter: pwd

The result of query should be: 
pwd/1
pwd/2
pwd/3....

Comment: Are you looking for this:
`where field like @pwd + '%';`

Comment: @KieranQuinn `@pwd` is not valid Oracle syntax. Were you meaning to use a bind variable `:pwd` or a substitution variable `&pwd` or just a PL/SQL variable `pwd`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bind variable `:parameter` then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  value LIKE :parameter || '/%'
```

So for some test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'pwd/1'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'pwd/2'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'pwdtest/1' FROM DUAL;
```

If `:parameter` is `pwd` then the output is:

> ```
> ID | VALUE
> -: | :----
>  1 | pwd/1
>  2 | pwd/2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b0f58a1a6cd00a5195b1ef392411f2ab)*